# Como generar varibles con el codigo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

quiero saber si se puede generar varibles con el codigo. Por ejemplo que el usuario introduzca la cantidad de varibles a crear.

```
        int cant_varibles;
        int num_filas = 5;
        int num_columnas = 8;

        Console.Write("Introduzca la cantidad de varibles: ");
        string linea = Console.ReadLine();
        cant_varibles = Convert.ToInt32(linea);

        for (int i = 0; i < cant_varibles; i++)
        {
            new double[,] valor_i = new double[num_filas, num_columnas];
        }
```

Obviamente este código me da error, solo pongo como guía de lo que deseo hacer, espero haberme explicado.

Comment: La respuesta es NO. Las variables deben estar previamente declaradas a la ejecución (y compilación, claro). Pero puedes utilizar un Array o en un List para ello. Tendrás una funcionalidad parecida.

Comment: Gracias.
Si de un principo pense usar un array o List. Hice esta pregunta por curiocidad, la tecnica de @Yoadad me funciono.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Algo así tal vez? Ojalá puedas dar más detalle de cual es el objetivo de tu código.

```
int cant_varibles;
int num_filas = 5;
int num_columnas = 8;
var listaVariables = new List<double[,]>();

Console.Write("Introduzca la cantidad de varibles: ");
string linea = Console.ReadLine();
cant_varibles = Convert.ToInt32(linea);

for (int i = 0; i < cant_varibles; i++)
{
    listaVariables.Add(new double[num_filas, num_columnas]);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Variable {0}: {1}", i, listaVariables[i]));
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

No olvides:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Comment: La respuesta es correcta, pero deberia decir bien en grande que no se generan variables.. si no que se generan valores para guardar, lo cual es muy diferente a generar variables...